# how update panel do partial postback and server side function is invoked and control UI updated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

i search google lot to know how update panel do the partial postback. if i have one button & one label inside update panel and when i click on button inside update panel then a partial postback occur and button click server side event called. if button click routine change the label value then effect we get after partial postback...i just need to how update panel call server side function and read the response and update control UI at cliend side.. what kind of javascript it generate and call to make partial postback and how it update UI.

if possible then please discuss this all in details with sample javascript that update panel generate to handle all the postback and UI updation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally new to AJAX (which stands for stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML), the [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) entry on wikipedia is a good starting point there are some more links like [Link1](http://www.interaktonline.com/support/articles/Details/AJAX:+Asynchronously+Moving+Forward-How+does+AJAX+work?.html?id_art=36&id_asc=308) or [Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163363.aspx):

```
Like DHTML and LAMP, AJAX is not a technology in itself, but a group of technologies. AJAX uses a combination of:

    HTML and CSS for marking up and styling information.
    The DOM accessed with JavaScript to dynamically display and interact with the information presented.
    A method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server, thereby avoiding page reloads. The XMLHttpRequest (XHR) object is usually used, but sometimes an IFrame object or a dynamically added tag is used instead.
    A format for the data sent to the browser. Common formats include XML, pre-formatted HTML, plain text, and JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). This data could be created dynamically by some form of server-side scripting.
```

As you can see, from a pure technological point of view, there is nothing really new here. Most of AJAX parts were already there in 1994 (1999 for the XMLHttpRequest object). The real novelty was to use these parts together as Google did with GMail (2004) and Google Maps (2005). Actually, both sites contributed heavily to the promotion of AJAX.

A picture being worth a thousand words, below a diagram that illustrates the communication between the client and the remote server, as well as the differences between the classic and the AJAX-powered applications:

[image]

For the orange part, you can do everything by hand (with the XMLHttpRequest object) or you can use famous JavaScript libraries like jQuery, Prototype, YUI, etc to "AJAXify" the client-side of your application. Such libraries aim to hide the complexity of JavaScript development (e.g. the cross-browser compatibility), but might be overkill for a simple feature.

On the server-side, some frameworks can help too (e.g. DWR or RAJAX if you are using Java), but all you need to do is basically to expose a service that returns only the required informations to partially update the page (initially as XML/XHTML - the X in AJAX - but JSON is often preferred nowadays).

Comment: Your first link (Link1) now redirects to Adobe.com!